# Nuget for UI consumption

Tags: asp.net, .net, nuget, nuget-package, nuget-spec

Is there anyway I can create nuget for the UI?
for example I have functionality which uses its own UI, when anyone consumes my package they should have ui integrated with there app with option to customize ui as per there app.